# The action Navigate with payload : SignIn was not handled by any navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am making an authentification flow using react native i have 3 screens Welcome Screen with two buttons to either sign in or sign up , i used react navigation version 5

every time i press either the sign in or sign up button i get the following error " The action Navigate with payload : SignIn was not handled by any navigator " and am not exactly sure why ?

my question is how do i resolve this issue and navigate correctly to the other screen

The code used for the app.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(authReducer, {
    token: null,
    errorMessage: "",
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
      dispatch({ type: "RESTORE_TOKEN", token: userToken });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // CLEARING ERROR MESSAGES WHEN SWITCHING SIGNIN-SIGNUP
      clearErrorMessage: async () => {
        dispatch({ type: "clear_error_message" });
      },
      // AUTOMATIC SIGNIN ONLY USING TOKENS ON USER DEVICE
      tryLocalSignin: async () => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
          // if token exists
          dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN", payload: token });

          navigation.navigate("MainTabScreen");
        } else {
          // if token doesnt exist
          navigation.navigate("Welcome");
        }
      },

      signIn: async ({ email, password }) => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        try {
          const response = await userAPI.post("/signin", { email, password });
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
          // using signin since the logic is the same
          dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN", token: response.data.token });
          // making use of the navigate component to access navigation
          // and redirect the user
          navigation.navigate("MainTabScreen");
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          dispatch({
            type: "add_error",
            payload: "Something went wrong with sign in",
          });
        }
      },
      signOut: async () => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_OUT" });

        navigation.navigate("Welcome");
      },
      signUp: async ({ email, password }) => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        try {
          const response = await userAPI.post("/signup", { email, password });
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
          dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN", payload: response.data.token });

          // making use of the navigate component to access navigation
          // and redirect the user
          navigation.navigate("MainTabScreen");
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({
            type: "add_error",
            payload: "Something went wrong with sign up",
          });
        }
      },
    }),
    []
  );
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {state.token === null ? <AuthNavigator /> : <AppNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The code used for signinScreen.js

```
const SigninScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require("../../assets/background.png")}
      style={styles.image}
    >
      {/*  <NavigationEvents onWillBlur={clearErrorMessage} /> */}
      <AuthForm
        headerText="Welcome back!"
        subText="Log in with your email and discover the universe."
        //errorMessage={state.errorMessage}
        AppOnSubmit={signIn}
        submitButtonText="Log in"
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

SigninScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerShown: false,
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //flex: 1,
    //justifyContent: "center",
    //marginBottom: 150,
  },
  image: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
});

export default SigninScreen;
```

AppNavigator.js :

```
const AppNavigator = () => (
 <AppTabs.Navigator
   initialRouteName="MainTabScreen"
   activeColor={colors.shade1}
   style={{ backgroundColor: "tomato" }}
 >
   <AppTabs.Screen
     name="Home"
     component={MainTabScreen}
     options={{
       tabBarColor: "#292B34",

       tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
         <SimpleLineIcons name="home" size={24} color={colors.shade2} />
       ),
     }}
   />

   <AppTabs.Screen
     name="SearchScreen"
     component={SearchScreen}
     options={{
       tabBarLabel: "Search",
       tabBarColor: "#292B34",
       tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
         <Feather name="search" size={24} color={colors.shade2} />
       ),
     }}
   />
   <AppTabs.Screen
     name="SaveScreen"
     component={SaveScreen}
     options={{
       tabBarLabel: "Save",
       tabBarColor: "#292B34",
       tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
         <Feather name="bookmark" size={24} color={colors.shade2} />
       ),
     }}
   />
   <AppTabs.Screen
     name="AccountScreen"
     component={AccountScreen}
     options={{
       tabBarLabel: "Account",
       tabBarColor: "#292B34",

       tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
         <MaterialCommunityIcons
           name="account-circle-outline"
           size={24}
           color={colors.shade2}
         />
       ),
     }}
   />
 </AppTabs.Navigator>
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

AuthNavigator.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#221e4f" },
      headerTintColor: "white",
      title: "",
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Welcome"
      component={WelcomeScreen}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="signIn" component={SigninScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignupScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Comment: What do `AuthNavigator` and `AppNavigator` look like?

Comment: You're calling `useNavigation()` inside a function. That's not allowed (hooks must always be called at the top level, not conditionally). Try moving the `const navigation` outside of that memo.

Answer (score 0):

This approach that you are doing is error prone. I believe, you shouldn't use `navigation.navigate('SomeScreen')` on your context functions.

For example; SIGN_IN action is dispatched and it will change the state of token which you are using as conditional to decide which navigator should it use. Dispatch function is not an async so you can't rely on React to change state and mount AppNavigator before `navigation.navigate("MainTabScreen")` is called. Instead use `initialRouteName="MainTabScreen"` prop.

I don't know anything about your AppNavigator or AuthNavigator but; misusing of this approach can cause the root of the problem. If you share more detail about your navigators we can help more.

Comment: hello thank you for your response , i will update my original question with the code for AppNavigator and AuthNavigator , basically my AppNavigator handles the navigation for the main screens of  the app , and my AppNavigator handles the screens for the authentification process

Comment: Hello @Erkin Kurt i updated the question with the additional information , can you please take a look ?

Comment: Is there any chances that you are navigating in your reducer? Because I can't see anything like `navigation.navigate('SignIn');` useNavigation shouldn't be in useMemo you need to use it in component, so remove useNavigation and define in component level, not in useMemo. Also can you please remove navigation.navigate('MainTabScreen'), as I said after dispatching you shouldn't need this. Let's remove it and see what happens.

Comment: after removing the stuff you told me to , i got the same following error : _The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"SignIn"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'SignIn'?_

btw when i use the appNavigator and Authnavigator on the App.js instead of calling them like in the code on my question i get no errors